# Java reflection can't access dynamically changed private field values

Tags: java, reflection

Here I am facing some difficulties while running the java reflection code i can't access dynamically changed field values in run time using reflection in java here i am putting my code  complete code snippets with outputs and expected outputs

Here is my Reflection Class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class Test1 {

    public void reflect() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        TestJava instance = new TestJava();

        Class<?> secretClass = instance.getClass();





        // Print all the field names & values

        Field fields[] = secretClass.getDeclaredFields();

        System.out.println("Access all the fields");

        for (Field field : fields) {

           System.out.println("Field Name: " + field.getName());
           if(field.getName().equals("i")) {
               field.setAccessible(true);

               System.out.println("For testing" +" "+field.get(instance) + "\n");
           }

           field.setAccessible(true);

           System.out.println(field.get(instance) + "\n");

        }

     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test1 newHacker = new Test1();
        TestJava secret = new TestJava();



        try {
           secret.increment();
          newHacker.reflect();
          secret.increment(); 
          newHacker.reflect();
          secret.increment();
          newHacker.reflect();
          secret.increment(); 
          newHacker.reflect();


        } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();

        }

      }


}
```

Here i am accessing the private variables from this class

```
public class TestJava {

   private  int i;

   public void increment() {
       i++;

       System.out.println("Testing i value" +" "+ i);
   }

}
```

The Out put of this program is

```
Testing i value 1
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 0

0

Testing i value 2
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 0

0

Testing i value 3
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 0

0

Testing i value 4
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 0

0
```

But the expected result is

```
Testing i value 1
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 1

1

Testing i value 2
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 2

2

Testing i value 3
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 3

3

Testing i value 4
Access all the fields
Field Name: i
For testing 4

4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Test1.reflect` uses a different instance of `TestJava` from the `secret` in `main`. (Notice there are two places where `new TestJava()` is called.) So calling `secret.increment()` won't affect the instance of `TestJava` used by `Test1.reflect`.

But if you did this:

```
public class Test1 {
    public void reflect(TestJava instance) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        // Everything in your original method minus the first line
    }
    // ...
}
```

and then used the following in `main`:

```
secret.increment();
newHacker.reflect(secret);
```

then things should behave as you expect.

Comment: You are right.But internally didn't understand  why this is not affecting.Can you please give a clue why ???

Comment: Fields are per-instance (unless we're dealing with static fields, but that's not the case here). So two different instances of an object will have independent values for the same field.